# curl: --data seems to be doing something differently that appending data to the URL

Tags: curl

I can do this:

```
$ curl -f -X GET -H X-Auth-Token:swordfish \
     http://deployer.corpwad.net/api/sites/commit?path=lows&revision=4550
site update
```

Yet, when I do this *properly* with the `--data` parameter:

```
$ curl -f -X GET -H X-Auth-Token:swordfish \
     --data path=lows \
     http://deployer.corpwad.net/api/sites/commit?revision=4550
site not found
```

When I use verbose output, I see this:

```
* About to connect() to deployer.corpwad.net port 80
 *   Trying XX.XX.XX.XX... connected
* Connected to deployer.corpwad.net (XX.XX.XX.XX) port 80
> GET /api/sites/commit?revision=3976 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> Host: deployer.corpwad.net
> Accept: */*
> X-Auth-Token:swordfish
> Content-Length: 9
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
> path=lowsHTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 22 Aug 2014 14:11:10 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, public
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

I take it that `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` wasn't added to my data, but was sent back from the server. When I append `path=lows` to the end of my data, the `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headings are not sent.

So, what am I doing wrong, or misunderstanding with the `--data` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first command line you issue a curl GET request (you don't need -X GET for that in that line, it is the default action when given a plain URL).

--data provides the data to use in the request body. That's the payload curl sends in the request. It is not part of the URL, it is not part of any header. When sending a request body like that, curl also includes the Content-Length and Content-Type headers you observe.

--data implies POST by default. You override that with -X GET (and as I always say: -X should be used very rarely) so you send a GET request with a request body payload. A very unusual HTTP request - yet perfectly valid HTTP spec wise.

curl also has a -G option that converts what you pass in with the --data option and puts that data at the end of the URL and instead makes it a GET request.

Comment: Ah, that's what I need! The "-G" option. Thanks.